# How to include blank spaces " " in a hyperlink in JSON when formatting a SharePoint List Column

Tags: json, sharepoint

I am attempting to include a link to a specific SharePoint List Item in an email using JSON formatting, but the URL contains spaces, which I can't seem to include in the hyperlink.

I have tried using ***"%20"*** as well as **"*x0020*"** in place of the space, but this is just read as a space.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "style": {
                "padding-right": "8px"
            },
            "txtContent": "@currentField.title"
        },
        {
            "elmType": "a",
            "attributes": {
                "iconName": "Mail",
                "class": "sp-field-quickActions",
                "href": {
                    "operator": "+",
                    "operands": [
                        "mailto:",
                        "@currentField.email",
                        "?subject=Task status&body=Hi ","@currentField.title",", Please see below link to a Shared Services Team Task which requires your attention.\r\n\r\n---\r\n",
                        "\r\nClick this link for more info. https://MyCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/SharedServicesDepartment/Lists/Task Management Register/DispForm.aspx?ID=",
                        "[$ID]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is a hyperlink of

[*https://MyCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/SharedServicesDepartment/Lists/Task Management Register/DispForm.aspx?ID=*](http://#)

But it cuts the hyperlink off at the first Space and leaves the last part as just text.

[*https://MyCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/SharedServicesDepartment/Lists/Task*](http://#) 
   Management Register/DispForm.aspx?ID=

Comment: How is the JSON generated? If it is by a program, please share **what you tried** to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the JSON formatting below to achieve it.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "style": {
                "padding-right": "8px"
            },
            "txtContent": "@currentField.title"
        },
        {
            "elmType": "a",
            "attributes": {
                "iconName": "Mail",
                "class": "sp-field-quickActions",
                "href": {
                    "operator": "+",
                    "operands": [
                        "mailto:",
                        "@currentField.email",
                        "?subject=Task status&body=Hi ","@currentField.title",", Please see below link to a Shared Services Team Task which requires your attention.\r\n\r\n---\r\n",
                        "\r\nClick this link for more info. <https://MyCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/SharedServicesDepartment/Lists/Task Management Register/DispForm.aspx?ID=",
                        "[$ID]",
                        ">"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Reference: [Add links containing spaces to an e-mail message](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-links-containing-spaces-to-an-e-mail-message-65e3086b-8f1c-4e4c-88ab-7489b3c823b1)

Comment: Adding a "<" & ">" either side of the URL worked perfectly. Thanks.